# Accessing nested object in Drools Decision table

Tags: jboss, drools, redhat-brms

I Have a RuleRequest Class which internally contains Product class and Policy Class. I have rules to check for attribute inside Product and Policy class. I need to do it in Excel based decision table.

I tried below.
First declared variable ruleRequest: RuleRequest here i tested i am able to access attributes of ruleRequest class like ruleRequestID. Now i have other conditions

Product(productDescription==$param), similarly Policy(policyDesc==$param)

This is unable to resolve Product(productDescription==$param) kind of value.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose from this description. You should provide a digest of the fact classes and an exact layout of the spreadsheet cells.

Answer (score 0):

I am quality engineer for decision tables at RedHat, however it is hard to help without the given table. Do you think would it be possible to upload it somewhere? At least screenshots could help or something.